# Android Intent for deep-linking to Deezer Search

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, deezer, android-implicit-intent

I am trying to perform a search on Deezer by sending the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.deezer.com/search/" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

In a previous version the web browser opened with a link saying "Open in Deezer" (or the like).
But in the current version this doesn't work anymore.

Is there any way to open the Deezer app and perform a search?
I have already tried the following (without success):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://search/" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/search/" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

The `scheme` of the `Uri` needs to be `deezer`. You have set it as `http`.

Try this. This should work.

Answer (score 5):

There are many deeplinks you can use to search for content inside the Deezer app. You do have the basic search like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/search/" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

But you can also be more precise :

```
// Search for an artist, will display the best match
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer-query://www.deezer.com/artist?query" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);

// Search for an album, will display the best match
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer-query://www.deezer.com/album?query" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);

// Search for a track, will display the best match
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer-query://www.deezer.com/track?query" + query));
this.startActivity(intent);
```